# Big data and hadoop exception when running a Map reduced programme

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I got the WordCount.java code from the internet and I tried to run it in eclipse after including the necessary libraries. But the code throws this exception:

```
2015-05-27 17:48:24,759 WARN  util.NativeCodeLoader     
(NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.init(JobClient.java:470)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.<init>(JobClient.java:449)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:832)
at MapReduce.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:57)
```

Can you tell me what does this mean and how can i resolve it?
I am very much new to Big data, Hadoop and map reduced programmes so please explain in detail. Thanks!

Comment: Your mapreduce server seems to be not configured properly. What configurations did you do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is short of the native library. In the ${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native, there are some execute files, try to add these files to your config.